# Vuforia + Project Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, google-project-tango

I managed to integrate both the Tango SDK and Vuforia into my Unity project by mergin the two versions of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

My `Vuforia Camera Prefab` is a child of the `Tango Delta Camera Prefab` and is set up, so that it should be the center of the AR-world.

When a target is detected, I instanciate an object with no parent in the scene to move around it with the `Tango Delta Camera`.

However the tracking of the `Tango Camera` seems to malfunction when the `Vuforia Camera` is active - it is still working, but the motion detection is very wrong.

Could it be that Vuforia is blocking Tango from using the camera? How would I resolve this?

Comment: tricky. I believe Qualcomm does not own Vuforia anymore. Is there a tango HAL layer on top of Android HAL?

Comment: Yup, they sold it. I don't know how either of the libraries access the camera, but I know that calling `Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit ();` or `VuforiaManager.Instance.Deinit();` before enabling the Tango gameObjects does not work.

Comment: It is highly possible that the Vuforia and Tango is fighting for the camera resources. As there's only one process can access the camera hardware at the same time, if Vuforia is occupying the camera, then the Tango Service will not be able to access it, thus the tracking will not be available. That's just a guess, could you double check to see if Tango connected successfully?

Comment: @JasonGuo I am 100% sure that Tango is connected, since the Tango UX opperates like it should and the accelerometer and depth sensor appear to work. Is there a way to deinitialize Vuforia so it will release the camera? Destroying the GameObjects and then activiating the Tango-GameObjects did not work.

Comment: @JasonGuo I guess you are a Googler? if so, can you also shed some light on the Tango HAL vs typical HAL layer? from an architectural perspective if possible (assuming of course a Tango HAL still exists)

Answer (score 3):

I am also working on same & what I have learned yet is,

- **Basic-**

Augmented reality can take many forms. It always depends in one form or another on a technique to calculate the relative 3D space to the reality around us.From Vast scope, if we consider Computer vision tracking AR. we can differentiate it into-

1. Marker based Tracking
2. Marker less Tracking

The where might involve areas like 2-D image matching and tracking, 3-D object matching and tracking, face detection and tracking, SLAM tracking, and location tracking (using GPS, accelerometer, compass, gyroscope). 
from these two,

---

- **Vuforia uses-**
  Computer Vision technology to recognize and track planar images **(Image Targets)** and simple 3D objects, such as boxes, in real-time. This image registration capability enables developers to position and orient virtual objects, such as 3D models and other media, in relation to real world images when these are viewed through the camera of a mobile device. **Its Marker based tracking.**
- **Project Tango-**
  is a bid to equip every mobile device with a powerful suite of software and sensors that can capture a complete 3D picture of the world around it, in real-time.Project Tango is a platform that uses computer vision to give devices the ability to understand their position relative to the world around them. The Project Tango Tablet Development Kit is an Android device with a wide-angle camera, a depth sensing camera, accurate sensor timestamping, and a software stack that enables application developers to use motion tracking, area learning and depth sensing. **In short, Its marker less tracking.**

[image]

---

- **Conclusion**
  Your efforts are really precious , but you are rendering AR using two different technology on same camera at a same time . i think it will obviously create conflict.

**You can use both in same app for different purposes without interfering in between.**